# Calculate specific value from arrays - only one number from array could be used

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have the following situation: I receive List of arrays of integer - could be 1, 2, 3 and more arrays. Example of arrays is {0, 1, 2} {1, 2, 3, 4} {0, 1, 2} {4} - could be of any size and could be equal, and **if there is more than 1 element in array - they are always consecutive and in ascending order**.
I need to check is it possible to get 5 as sum of any elements of array, numbers should be taken from every array but only one number from each array can be used.
I don't need to find all possible combinations, once I encounter sum = 5, function return true.

Thanks for any help.

The question was closed.
With corrected description the solution became very simple:
I just have to check 2 conditions:
 -- if sum of every first element is more than 5 - return False (because all other elements of arrays are greater than previous as they are consecutive and ascending)
 -- if sum of last elements is less than 5 - return False (same explanation as above)
So I just check

```vb
Dim sumMin as Integer 'sum of first elements
Dim sumMax as Integer 'sum of last elements

'loop List of arrays and get sumMin and sumMax

If sumMin <= 5 And sumMax >= 5 Then
    Return True
Else 
    Return False 
End if
```

Comment: Can you take the same numerical value from a different array? In your example arrays... 1 from the first array, 3 from the second array and 1 from the third array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim query = _
    From x In {0, 1, 2}
    From y In {1, 2, 3, 4}.StartWith(0) ' 0 means not chosen
    From z In {0, 1, 2}
    From w In {4}.StartWith(0) ' 0 means not chosen
    Where x + y + z + w = 5
    Select { x, y, z, w }
```

That gives me:

```
0, 0, 1, 4 
0, 1, 0, 4 
0, 3, 2, 0 
0, 4, 1, 0 
1, 0, 0, 4 
1, 2, 2, 0 
1, 3, 1, 0 
1, 4, 0, 0 
2, 1, 2, 0 
2, 2, 1, 0 
2, 3, 0, 0
```

Comment: thank you for reply. but I don't have fixed number of arrays - I have List of arrays, quantity of arrays can be different. I need some loop through all my arrays. And size of arrays is always different, not fixed.

Comment: @OleksandrPavlov - It's a little more complicated. It'll take a bit of recursion and selection, but it'll take a bit more thinking to get it simple.